# display maths formula using Javascript <MathJax >

Tags: mathjax

This works in HTML
When (a \ne 0), there are two solutions to (ax^2 + bx + c = 0) and they are  $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$$
Solve QE by formula method: $$x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$$

How to update and display from javascript code?

document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=bxno;

```
if(d==0){
    document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d = 0, Roots are Real and equal.";
   }
else if(d>0){
        document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d > 0, Roots are Real and not equal.";
        }
else if(d<0)
    {
        document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d < 0, Roots are Imaginery.";
    }
```

document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=bxno;

```
if(d==0){
    document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d = 0, Roots are Real and equal.";
   }
else if(d>0){
        document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d > 0, Roots are Real and not equal.";
        }
else if(d<0)
    {
        document.getElementById("Outputl2").innerHTML="d < 0, Roots are Imaginery.";
    }
```